# How to change when Jquery edits my CSS upon reaching an anchor point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, anchor

I've found this piece of Jquery to change CSS when it reaches an anchor point.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPosition = scrollY || pageYOffset;

    if (scrollPosition > $("#someAnchor").position().top - $(window).height()) {
        alert("run code here");
    }
});
```

The problem is it does so when the bottom of the screen reaches the anchor point, but it needs to run the code when the top touches the anchor point. How do I do this?

Comment: most obvious you would remove the `- $(window).height()` piece.  However I'm really hoping you're not intending on modifying the display or moving windows as the user scrolls .... there is a place reserved in Heck....

Comment: Does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping this works well for you:

```
var ranOffsetCode = false

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  var docScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop(); // Figure out how far we scrolled.
  var someAnchorTop = $('#someAnchor').offset().top - $('#someAnchor').height(); // Figure out how far down the element is on the page

  if (docScrollTop >= someAnchorTop) { // If we scrolled up to or past the element, fire this
    if (ranOffsetCode === false) { // This makes sure we only run the function once and not every scroll
      ranOffsetCode = true;
      console.log('run code here'); // Functional code to execute after we scrolled down this far.
    }
  }
  else {
    ranOffsetCode = false;
  }

});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/mutaje/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `- $(window).height()`

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() { var scrollPosition = scrollY || pageYOffset;

if (scrollPosition > $("#someAnchor").position().top) { alert("run code here"); } });
```

Comment: @Jorden Sandel it should work.  There's something else wrong in your code (which you don't show)

Answer (score 0):

Not really meant to be an answer, but it might help:

```
var spam = false;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPosition = scrollY || pageYOffset;

    $('#pos').html( 'y: '+scrollY+', a: '+$("#someAnchor").position().top + ', p: '+scrollPosition );
    if (!spam && (scrollPosition > $("#someAnchor").position().top)) {
        alert('hit it!');
        spam = true;
    }
});
```

Some html:

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:85%; width:15%; height:20px">
<span id="pos" style="font-family:Courier; font-size:0.5em; white-space:pre"></span>
</div>
```